# Makefile rule for yarn build - how to express a dependency for copy deployment artefacts

Tags: makefile, yarnpkg

I am building an image for a network camera, where the application is written in **C** but the output image also contains a bundled **web-app** that if deployed to the camera's embedded web-service.

We use **make** to build the image and I use **yarn** to build the web-app. I want to create a makefile rule, so that I don't execute `yarn build` every time I build the image. Currently I have:

```
$(WEBAPP_PATH)/build: $(WEBAPP_PATH)
    @echo Building web-app...
    @pushd $(WEBAPP_PATH); yarn build; popd;
```

and

```
$(PACKAGE_PATH)/html: $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build $(PACKAGE_PATH)/.dir
    @echo Copy html...
    mkdir -p $@
    cp -r $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build/index.html $@/
    cp -r $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build/js $@/
```

But how can I write a more granular check for the need to build the bundle?

**Update:** The my question is really how to detect that the web-app build artefacts are updated, given that their names are random.

Comment: What is the desired criterion for when you would like to trigger a rebuild of the webapp---whenever a new image is written from the camera?  I presume from context that you're seeing the `$(WEBAPP_PATH)/build` target is executed on every run of Make.  Is it marked `PHONY`?  (I am also presuming that 'bundle' is the content of the `$(WEBAPP_PATH)/build` directory)

Comment: I want to avoid to rebuild the web app every time I run make. On the other hand I want to detect when the bundle is updated and I want to run yarn when input have been touched.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit sloppy but WEBAPP_PATH is where the yarn.lock files and the web app project I found. PACKAGE_PATH is where the intermediates for the image is found. The bundle is copied there before inking it all.

Comment: I'm confused why you're seeing the `$(WEBAPP_PATH)/build` target fire.  Once that directory exists, you shouldn't see it run the yarn steps again...unless it's marked `PHONY`, or you're deleting it as part of the build.

Comment: That’s really what I am asking about - ideally I want to replace $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build with what yarn outputs, but appear from index.html, the files produced have names that are random. So how can I detect changes?

Comment: You should update the question to include that, or other readers might miss what you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems like the following might produce the effect you want:

1) Add a step to the rule that runs yarn: make it `touch` a file. Then make the target of that rule be the touch-file.  This rule's dependencies should be updated to list all of the inputs that signal when yarn needs to be run again.  (Note: if index.html's timestamp is bumped every time that yarn runs, then you can use it instead of the touchfile and touch step.)

```
$(WEBAPP_PATH)/touchfile: $(WEBAPP_PATH) $(YARN_INPUTS)
    @echo Building web-app...
    @pushd $(WEBAPP_PATH); yarn build; popd;
    touch $(WEBAPP_PATH)/touchfile
```

2) Then update your bundle-copy rule to depend on the timestamp of the touchfile as a surrogate for all of the random-named files.  Also update the target of this rule to be the copy of index.html that it produces.

```
$(PACKAGE_PATH)/html/index.html: $(WEBAPP_PATH)/touchfile $(PACKAGE_PATH)/.dir
    @echo Copy html...
    mkdir -p $@
    cp -r $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build/index.html $@/
    cp -r $(WEBAPP_PATH)/build/js $@/
```

3) The rule that performs the link step can then specify `$(WEBAPP_PATH)/build/index.html` as a dependency, because the `copy` will update its timestamp, and thereby trigger the link rule.